# How to remove footer from just homepage

Tags: customization, css, footer

I just want to hide the footer from the homepage and the rest of the website footer should remain the same. how can i do that? here is my website http://texmex-cantina.com/
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, we help people with problems with their own coding here.  Can you post your code and explain what you have tried?

Answer (score 1):

You can copy the footer.php file to your child theme and add condition to not display on home page.

```
if (!is_home() || ! is_front_page()){
    // All the codes which are not supposed to display on the front page or home page
}
```

Comment: Instead of child theme, Can i add this code the parent theme?

Comment: you can, but it'd not recommended because if you update parent theme then it'll be lost after you update the theme, and you will have to re apply.

Comment: Should i replace your code with some other codes in footer.php? i tried to put it at the end of footer.php but it didn't worked out.

Comment: which all div's do you want to remove? you can put all under this condition.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your theme, Wordpress has a front-page.php file that will act as the home page if present and set.  This would allow you to use it as a separate page template from the rest of your site.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Static_Front_Page#Configuration_of_front-page.php